# Does Google Earth or Google Maps Support Multi Touch?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, multi-touch

Could someone give me some information about whether Google Earth or Google Maps supports Multi - Touch or not in Windows? Where can I find the relevant information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good idea to let us know if you're talking about the full desktop Google Earth (ie. with the COM API) or the thin client web based app.

That being said -- neither versions support touch events natively. Both applications are extremely "mouse heavy" and do virtually all interaction via the mouse. You basically have to map all the touch events to mouse events and go from there. This isn't exactly easy, and requires a lot of low level WinAPI programming -- so it might be easier to get some overlay that does the mouse translation for you.

I personally haven't used the wrapper that Kevin posted, but it looked interesting -- so that might work for you.

---

EDIT: Kevin's suggestion uses TUIO, which is a pretty popular way of going from touch --> mouse events. In my experience this doesn't do a very good job for Google Earth though, which relies on your typical "mouse down, mouse move, mouse up" patterns ---- this can be done in TUIO, but the actual gestures to get mouse down/move/up actions are clunky.

-- Dan

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. Does the same apply for Google Maps too?

Comment: If you're using Google Maps you're using the JavaScript thin client, and the same situation would apply. Please up-vote or accept the answers you find most useful (click the check mark and/or the up arrow in the margin to the left of the post) :-).